# Allocating and Freeing pointer to pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I'm attempting to pass a pointer to a pointer (char**) into a function that will initialize it, and then pass it into another function that will free the memory, however I'm getting seg faults on the freeing which leads me to believe my allocation is going wrong.

Valgrind is reporting use of uninitalized value at this line. tmp[i] is pointing to 0x0.

```
if(tmp[i]) free((char*)tmp[i]);
```

Here is the code (this is only test code)

```
void 
alloc_strings(char ***test, int count) 
{
  char **tmp = *test;
  tmp = malloc(count * sizeof(char*));

  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    tmp[i] = malloc(6);
    strcpy(tmp[i],"Hello");
  }
}

void
free_strings(char ***test, int count)
{
  char **tmp = *test;

  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if(tmp[i]) free((char*)tmp[i]);
  }

  if(tmp)
    free(tmp);
}
```

And the invocation:

```
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  char **test;
  alloc_strings(&test, 10);
  free_strings(&test, 10);

  return 0;
}
```

I have been playing around with this for a while, reading up on pointers etc however can't get my head around the issue. Any thoughts greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign to `*test`, not to assign from it. How about:

```
void 
alloc_strings(char ***test, int count) 
{
    char **tmp = malloc(count * sizeof *tmp);
    /*...*/
    *test = tmp;
}
```

Comment: exactly. twice (also in the destructor)

Comment: @wildplasser I think the destructor is fine, just a little overcomplicated.

Comment: It is fine (it destructs ...) , but you'd expect it to set `*test=NULL;`, too before returning. (BTW: the constructor has a potential memoryleak, if *test happens to point to a previously allocated array)

Comment: @cnicutar That's great thank you, I think I understand however will need to spend more time on this. As for the destructor it was just quick and dirty when moving code around. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In the code example,

```
alloc_strings(char ***test, int count) 
{
    char **tmp = *test;
```

`*test` should have some space to store a pointer to `char **` which currently is not allocated. Hence, if the example is as this

```
char** array[1];

alloc_strings(&array[0], 7);
```

I feel that the code will work.